# How to pass arguments to filtered workspaces separately using Turborepo?

Tags: vercel, monorepo, turborepo

My use case is, I have two workspaces say `foo` and `bar`, and I want to pass the different command line args, is it possible to achieve such functionality with Turborepo.

I want to do something like this:

```
turbo run dev --filter="foo" -- --env=dev --filter="bar" -- --env=local
```